# How to make the method bellow to return all arguments from the constructor

Tags: javascript

I am still learning Javascript. Now, I am trying to return the value of `name` and `age` from the `constructor(name, age)` bellow. Whenever I try it returns either the value of `age` or `name` but not both.

```js
class User{
    constructor(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    myFunction(){
        return function() {
            return name;
            return age;
        }
    }
}

let user = new User("Justin",30);
let call = user.myFunction();
alert(call());
```

Comment: myFunction()
  {
    return function() 
 {
      return (name);
    }
 myFunction2()
 {
  return function() 
 {
      return (age);
    }
}      //is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** return multiple values in JavaScript. However, you can put all the values you want to return into an array and return that array.

```js
class User{
    constructor(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    myFunction(){
        return function() {
            return [this.name,this.age]
        }.bind(this);
    }
}

let user = new User("Justin",30);
let call = user.myFunction();
console.log(call());
```

---

Output

```js
[ 'Justin', 30 ]
```